# Retrieve multiple rows which is not in an array of values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have a table which contains id (5 digit number) and other details. I have an array which contains some of the id's in that table. My task is to retrieve rows whose id's not in that array. I've tried some ways.

Here is the code what i've done so far..

This is the array, **$cids** is the id's i have fetched using query.

```
$camp=implode(",",$cids);
```

Query :

```
SELECT campaign_id FROM tab_camp WHERE country='$country' OR country='All Countries' AND campaign_id NOT IN('$camp')";
```

But this query is not giving the result. Can anyone help me to write query..??

Comment: how many elements this array contains ?

Comment: first consider using prepared Statement instead of hardcoding it into the query for security purpose

Answer (score 0):

the sql should be like this

```
$sql = "SELECT campaign_id FROM tab_camp WHERE (country='$country' OR country='All Countries') AND campaign_id NOT IN($camp)";
```

Answer (score 0):

The list for the IN operator is a comma separated list of values, not a single string with comma separated items. Omit the single quotes:

```
SELECT 
    campaign_id 
FROM 
    tab_camp 
WHERE 
    country='$country' 
OR 
    country='All Countries' 
AND 
    campaign_id NOT IN($camp)
```

If I understand you correctly, you get this array of ids from another query. If that's the case, you could use a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    campaign_id 
FROM 
    tab_camp 
WHERE 
    country='$country' 
OR 
    country='All Countries' 
AND 
    campaign_id NOT IN(SELECT <your ids> FROM other ....)
```

**Note:**

You should have a look at PDO or mysqli and use prepared statements with placeholders to bind your input values to. This will take care of sql injection, but of quoting too.